# Code First and many-to-many relations

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Hopefully someone can show me how to implement this many-to-may relation...

I have two classes, Car and Owner. Each Car can be owned by many Owners. And each owner can own many cars. Note that I only want a navigationproperty from car to owners.

```
public partial class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
}

public partial class Owner
{
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my DbInitializer I seed the b like this.

```
        Owner owner1 = new Owner() { OwnerId = 10, Name = "Erik" };
        context.Owners.Add(owner1);
        Car b1 = new Car() { CarId = 1, Name = "Volvo", Owners = new List<Owner>(new Owner[] { owner1 }) };
        Car b2 = new Car() { CarId = 2, Name = "Saab", Owners = new List<Owner>(new Owner[] { owner1 }) };
        context.Cars.Add(b1);
        context.Cars.Add(b2);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

The result is that owner1 only owns b2. Why? And how can it be changed to a many to many relation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you context add this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().HasMany(c => c.Owners).WithMany();
}
```

I tells EF that there is a many-to-many association between `Car` and `Owner` without a navigation property in `Owner`.

Comment: Thank you, but...As noted above, can it be done without a navigationproperty from Owner to Cars?